# ssrs-creating multiple rows in data region and display no data message if no data

Tags: reporting-services

I am using the table without data region . I set the No row message to "no data found", but my report returns empty table structure with column values . how to get only message .

Answer (score 0):

You must have some data set for the report.

You can show or hide the tablix by doing a count of the data set.

set the visibility expression of the tablix  to

`=iif(countrows("yourdatasetname")=0,true,false)`

You can also place a text box over the tablix with the "No rows to show" message as it's text and set the visibility of the text box to be opposite of the tablix.

`=iif(countrows("yourdatasetname")<>0,true,false)`